# Proper way for best fidelity to ground 1980's pro audio mixer, will grounding to the case create noise?

Tags: grounding

love this forum, this is my first post so "beer" with me.
I am modding an old 1989 tascam mixer.  I know its probably easier to just buy something nicer, but I got it for free and I want to use it as a learning experiance, both in soldering new parts in, and in theory.  I have limited study in electric circuits but was a long time ago. I know some basics.  The mixer came orig with 2 prong no ground.  Someone has modded to add a ground and bonded it to the case. Now I havn't turned it on becuase the caps are toast and I am building a new power supply that is in its own case with a new transformer/caps.  So I can change the power supply so it is isolated and then I wouldn't need to bond the case to the mains ground I think? I just don't want to have the mains ground bonded to the case if possible to keep unwanted noise out. The mixer has balanced and unbalanced circuits.  I am changing the op amps to LME49724, and changing some resistors and faders.

Comment: @mhbuur how's a chassis ground different from a mains ground ?

Comment: @S.Ramjit I realise my comment was not of much use. I would simply do some tests where grounds are not connected (mixer, PSU and mains) and tests where they are (in different combinations). That should reveal the optimal grounding scheme for that setup. Perhaps introduce ground lift switches